# pictures as objects in app with java

Tags: java, android

i was scouting the web, and maybe im just terrible but i couldn't find a answer.
I'm currently making a game with a friend as a project, and we wonder, how you can
implent any kinds of pictures into the code.
We wanna do the following:
Create an male / female character.
implent pictures with hats, shoes, all kinds of things that you can put on this avater.
And last thing get a background for the game.
I'm not asking for a bunch of code, only for advise for where to look. since we are pretty new on this subject.
The game is gonna be in 2D. so if you know a good program that interacts well with java
In advance thanks for helping.
Michael.

Comment: Google search 2d Graphics, Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use images in multiple ways. For instance you can use it to add it to a JLabel as an icon:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("pathtoimg.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
```

If you do that you might need to do this:

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

This is just a small and quick example, I'm sure you will find what you need by Googling "images in java" or something like that. The Oracle Docs should also be plenty of information you could use.